# Iterate over values of Map to render all icon components but don't work however render one icon works

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing react-native project.

I have a function which set icon metadata into a `Map` :

```
export function getIconsMetadata() {
   // a map of icons' metadata
   const iconsMetadata = new Map();
   ...
   // code to set icon metadata to the map
   iconsMetadata.set("foo", "Foo");
   iconsMetadata.set("bar", "Bar");
    ...
   return iconsMetadata;
}
```

There is another function which returns the actual icon component based on the icon type (i.e. the value of `iconsMetadata` holds the icon type):

```
export function getMyIcon(iconType) {
  switch (iconType) {
    case 'Foo':
      return <Foo />;
    case 'Bar':
      return <Bar />;
    ...
}
```

In my screen, I have a function to show icon component by iterating over the values of the above icons' metadata `Map`, and try to render each icon component:

```
export const MyScreen() => {
    const showIcons = () => {
      [...getIconsMetadata().values()].map((iconType, index) => {
    
        const iconComponent = getMyIcon(iconType);
        return <View key={index}>
                 {iconComponent}
               </View>;
    
          });
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {/*I call the showIcons function here to render icons*/}
          {showIcons()}
      </View>
   )

}
```

Problem is the icons are not shown on screen.

But if I directly return **one** icon component in my screen:

```
export const MyScreen = () => {
    ...
    const showOneIcon = () => {
        return <View>
                     <Foo />
                   </View>;
        
              });
    }
    
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              {/*I show one icon*/}
              {showOneIcon()}
          </View>
       )
}
```

The `<Foo />` icon component is rendered successfully on the screen.

So, why iterating the map to show all icons don't work?

Comment: Try to check if you have other elements that could have the same key. Maybe another map function with key={index}.

Comment: I tried removing the key, also tried other key, results are the same, it is not because of the key but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you’re not returning anything from showIcons. Either you remove { } from there

```
const showIcons = () =>
  [...getIconsMetadata().values()].map((iconType, index) => {
    const iconComponent = getMyIcon(iconType);
    return <View key={index}>{iconComponent}</View>;
  });
```

or add return before `[...getIconsMetadata().values()].map`

```
const showIcons = () => {
  return [...getIconsMetadata().values()].map((iconType, index) => {
    const iconComponent = getMyIcon(iconType);
    return <View key={index}>{iconComponent}</View>;
  });
};
```

Comment: How can I miss that `return`? Thank you!